# IO.Ports.SerialPort connection fail

Tags: .net, serial-port, communication

I develop a software using .net framework (2.0). I communicate with several devices using serial port without any problem.

However, I try to communicate with a new one, but impossible to write or read any command.

Before try any communication using my software, I test it before with *HyperTerminal* from *Hilgraeve*. So with this soft if I send **IDN?* throw the serial port, the device switch to remote mode and answer something like *ANRITSU,MS9710A,V1.20383*. So parameters used seem good.

But, when I try to use IO.Ports.SerialPort from the .net framework, impossible to communicate. After many test I can say :

- It seem the problem comes from the Write function, because nothing seems to be written on the buffer when I use *MyPort.Write("*IDN?")*. I say that because the device doesn't switch to remote mode.
- All (visible) parameters are the same between HyperTerminal and my IO.Ports.SerialPort : 9600 bps, 8-N-1, no handshaking. Buffers size of IO.Ports.SerialPort have the default value.
- I've tested several other .net application find with google and no one are able to communicate with the device, I've also tested soft using framework 1.1 before MS add the IO.Ports.SerialPort to the framework.

So my conclusion is the problem come from the IO.Ports.SerialPort, but I don't know what is the problem. I have some clue :

- IO.Ports.SerialPort are not able to communicate when the speed is lower than 19200bps (9600 max in my case). I suppose that because all other devices with which I communicate without any problem have a speed of 19200bps minimum (edit : I've found an other device which work at 9600bps, and I arrive to communicate with it using my software, the problem comes from an other point)
- There is one parameter that I haven't seen which can solve the problem
- Does next version of the framework (3.0, 3.5 or 4.0) may help ? I don't find any documentation about update of IO.Ports.SerialPort class with last version.

So have you any idea about this problem ? Anybody have been had this kind of problem before ?

More some information : the soft is developed using vb.net with VS 2010 on Win 7. I've also tested GPIB communication on the problematic device without problem, but I prefer not use GPIB protocol if possible.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there any Exception been thrown out?

Comment: No, not any exception. After I call Write, the program continue and when I read the buffer after that, it return null string (because I think nothing is sent to the device.